# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string with DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datediff

I have looked at probably every other question, tried every other answer and nothing has worked so I am going to throw out what I am trying to do and hope I can get some help.

Here is what I am currently working on.

```
SELECT t1.SOURCE_ID, t1.[Agency Name], t1.[Title Name], t1.DESCR, t1.CREATED_DATE AS 'Reviewed Date', t2.CREATED_DATE AS 'Filed Dated', DateDiff(Day,'Filed Date','Reviewed Date') AS 'Difference' 
    FROM ((SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE, rp.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
    tv.DESCR, a.NAME as 'Agency Name', p.NAME as 'Title Name' FROM HISTORY AS h 
    INNER JOIN RULE_PACKET AS rp ON (h.SOURCE_ID = rp.RULE_PACKET_ID)
    INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS p ON (p.PROGRAM_ID = rp.PROGRAM_ID)
    INNER JOIN AGENCY AS a ON (a.AGENCY_ID = p.AGENCY_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE_V AS tv ON (tv.TYPE_ID = rp.ACTION_TYPE_ID)
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Rules Pre-Approved' OR h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'CPR Rules Pre-Approved') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE, rp.EFFECTIVE_DATE, tv.DESCR, a.NAME as 'Agency Name', p.NAME as 'Title Name' FROM HISTORY as h 
    INNER JOIN RULE_PACKET AS rp ON (h.SOURCE_ID = rp.RULE_PACKET_ID)
    INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS p ON (p.PROGRAM_ID = rp.PROGRAM_ID)
    INNER JOIN AGENCY AS a ON (a.AGENCY_ID = p.AGENCY_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE_V AS tv ON (tv.TYPE_ID = rp.ACTION_TYPE_ID)
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Standard Packet Filed') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t2 ON (t1.SOURCE_ID = t2.SOURCE_ID) AND ('Reviewed Date' >= 'Filed Date'));
```

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am trying to find how long it took to go from filed to reviewed.

When I take out the DateDiff function this is my code.

```
SELECT t1.SOURCE_ID, t1.[Agency Name], t1.[Title Name], t1.DESCR, t1.CREATED_DATE AS 'Reviewed Date', t2.CREATED_DATE AS 'Filed Dated' 
    FROM ((SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE, rp.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
    tv.DESCR, a.NAME as 'Agency Name', p.NAME as 'Title Name' FROM HISTORY AS h 
    INNER JOIN RULE_PACKET AS rp ON (h.SOURCE_ID = rp.RULE_PACKET_ID)
    INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS p ON (p.PROGRAM_ID = rp.PROGRAM_ID)
    INNER JOIN AGENCY AS a ON (a.AGENCY_ID = p.AGENCY_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE_V AS tv ON (tv.TYPE_ID = rp.ACTION_TYPE_ID)
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Rules Pre-Approved' OR h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'CPR Rules Pre-Approved') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE, rp.EFFECTIVE_DATE, tv.DESCR, a.NAME as 'Agency Name', p.NAME as 'Title Name' FROM HISTORY as h 
    INNER JOIN RULE_PACKET AS rp ON (h.SOURCE_ID = rp.RULE_PACKET_ID)
    INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS p ON (p.PROGRAM_ID = rp.PROGRAM_ID)
    INNER JOIN AGENCY AS a ON (a.AGENCY_ID = p.AGENCY_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE_V AS tv ON (tv.TYPE_ID = rp.ACTION_TYPE_ID)
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Standard Packet Filed') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t2 ON (t1.SOURCE_ID = t2.SOURCE_ID) AND ('Reviewed Date' >= 'Filed Date'));
```

And this is what it produces:

[Screen shot of results from SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfs1m.png)

Help please.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted/tabular text. Clearly the error is obvious, you have a date stored as a string (bad idea - you should never do that), which is failing to convert to a date. If you are struggling to find the offending data I recommend using `try_convert` in your where clause and seeing where is it null.

Comment: If you would stop using the archaic and deprecated `''` to quote column names and instead use `[]` you might have spotted the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'Reviewed Date' and 'Filed Dated' you need to use t1.CREATED_DATE  and t2.CREATED_DATE in datediff() function and where clause since column aliases are not allowed to be use in where clause or in select list.

When you are using 'Reviewed Date' or 'Filed Dated' in datediff() function those it's trying to convert string 'Reviewed Date' and 'Filed Dated' into date field which is not possible.

Please try this:

```
SELECT t1.SOURCE_ID, t1.[Agency Name], t1.[Title Name], t1.DESCR, t1.CREATED_DATE AS 'Reviewed Date', t2.CREATED_DATE AS 'Filed Dated', DateDiff(Day,t2.CREATED_DATE,t1.CREATED_DATE) AS 'Difference' 
    FROM ((SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE, rp.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
    tv.DESCR, a.NAME as 'Agency Name', p.NAME as 'Title Name' FROM HISTORY AS h 
    INNER JOIN RULE_PACKET AS rp ON (h.SOURCE_ID = rp.RULE_PACKET_ID)
    INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS p ON (p.PROGRAM_ID = rp.PROGRAM_ID)
    INNER JOIN AGENCY AS a ON (a.AGENCY_ID = p.AGENCY_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE_V AS tv ON (tv.TYPE_ID = rp.ACTION_TYPE_ID)
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Rules Pre-Approved' OR h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'CPR Rules Pre-Approved') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE, rp.EFFECTIVE_DATE, tv.DESCR, a.NAME as 'Agency Name', p.NAME as 'Title Name' FROM HISTORY as h 
    INNER JOIN RULE_PACKET AS rp ON (h.SOURCE_ID = rp.RULE_PACKET_ID)
    INNER JOIN PROGRAM AS p ON (p.PROGRAM_ID = rp.PROGRAM_ID)
    INNER JOIN AGENCY AS a ON (a.AGENCY_ID = p.AGENCY_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE_V AS tv ON (tv.TYPE_ID = rp.ACTION_TYPE_ID)
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Standard Packet Filed') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t2 ON (t1.SOURCE_ID = t2.SOURCE_ID) AND (t1.CREATED_DATE >= t2.CREATED_DATE));
```